# MVC ModelBinding to a List - Losing Items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Lets say a have the following Model

```
public class FirstModel
{
    public List<SecondModel> SecondModels { get; set; }
}

public class SecondModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this View

```
@model FirstModel

....
<input name="SecondModels[0].Value" value="test1"/>
<input name="SecondModels[1].Value" value="test2"/>
<input name="SecondModels[2].Value" value="test3"/>
...
```

The Modelbinding works good. I get the complete Model to my ActionMethod.

**But** if i remove the item in the middle using, for example, jQuery.

```
<input name="SecondModels[0].Value" value="test1"/>
<input name="SecondModels[2].Value" value="test3"/>
```

i lost the `SecondModels[2]` because the ModelBinder is unable to bind.
So i get only the first ("test1").

Is there another Syntax or CustomModelBinder which is able to bind this correctly, or do i need to replace the `input` names after removing the item ?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use **Non-Sequential Model Binding** feature of ASP.NET MVC here. In your case, you need something as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SecondModels.Index" value="0" />
<input name="SecondModels[0].Value" value="test1"/>

<input type="hidden" name="SecondModels.Index" value="2" />
<input name="SecondModels[2].Value" value="test3"/>
```

For more information, please have a look at **Non-Sequential Indices** part of Phil Haack's blog post:

[Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: Thats it ;) Thank you! I know the Haacked Article, but for any reason, i missed it.

Comment: @Xander This is how it works. If you are generating random fields on the fly, it is extremely hard to keep track of the index. On the other hand, you may just bind it this way, for example by making the index a GUID like: `<input type="hidden" name="SecondModels.Index" value="20AA658C-8AE4-41BA-875A-CC732FAC00DA" />`

Comment: @tugberk what!?!? you're saying it is difficult to re-index items in a list?

Comment: @dknaack I tried to find the Steve Sanderson's article on this topic but couldn't find it. He also has a great HTML helper for generating those field and it works great.

Comment: @Xander you're not getting the usage of this feature. If you are manipulating the DOM randomly by adding / removing form fields, how would you track the index?

Comment: @Xander this post explains the feature better: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: you don't track the index! you re-index the items in the list from `0 - n` on the client every time an item is *removed* or *added*

Comment: @Xander you are still not getting it. Read the article I posted above.

Comment: @Xander and think about that you have nested classes, that makes it very bad in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this on a past project ...

My quick and dirty solution was to re-index the list of items with their appropriate values.

**So this:**

```
<input name="SecondModels[0].Value" value="test1"/>
<input name="SecondModels[1].Value" value="test2"/>
<input name="SecondModels[2].Value" value="test3"/>
<input name="SecondModels[3].Value" value="test4"/>
<input name="SecondModels[4].Value" value="test5"/>
```

**Becomes this (when index 1 and 3 are removed):**

```
<input name="SecondModels[0].Value" value="test1"/>
<input name="SecondModels[1].Value" value="test3"/>
<input name="SecondModels[2].Value" value="test5"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i have right now. My question is, is there a better solution?

Comment: Xander, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that you're re-indexing ... My solution will re-bind to your model appropriately ...